# "He had all the money in the world; [yet/but] he was sad"

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Which one is the correct option, knowing that there is only one correct answer?

Comment: The Venn diagrams overlap substantially, but there are places where one is better than the other.  I see "yet" as having more of an element of surprise than "but." It was raining, yet the pavement did not become wet." vs. " It was raining, but we went out anyway."  "But" would work in the first sentence, but (not "yet") it would not communicate the sort of "behold!" attitude that "yet"  brings.  (I'm obsessive about each word having a unique purpose, and here, the ever-so-slight sense of wonder in "yet" gives it a reason to hang around.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the two. For example:

> Methuselah, the spoiling of death, is the longest liver in the world; yet he died in the year that the flood was upon the earth.
>
> These events are already some of the best hot rod and custom shows in the world; but this really gives you something unique to see at each event!

Answer (score 0):

The defence between both are very subtle and in most cases would not make much of a difference to what is being communicated.

Yet in these case is used to denote 'in spite of' or 'even though' to denote strongly that the first part of the sentence could have had a strong influence on the second but did not and often was surprised by the fact that it did not.

Egs:: John was my closest friend, yet he did not show up for my wedding.

But is used to simply suggest a contradiction or a possible alternative

Egs:: the sky appears clear now but it might still rain.